# Changing Permalinks to a Custom Permalink causes a 404 Error [no matter what I do]

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I've changed my permalinks to a custom one. When I saw my contact page was sitting on `[domain]/index.php/contact` instead of `[domain]/contact` *this isn't isolated to /contact however*. I went and deleted the index.php in the custom string. This came up with of course `[domain]/index.php/contact` redirecting to `[domain]/contact`. However this came up with a 404 error *page doesn't exist*.

I went and checked and the .htaccess file did not exist so I enabled htaccess and created the file with vim empty then changed the permissions with chmod to 644 as stated [the Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#.htaccess_permissions). Went and re-saved the permalinks to discover I still had a 404 error, this is when I noticed that WordPress still thought the .htaccess file was not writable.

I went and copied the .htaccess file text WordPress wanted me to manually add to the .htaccess file manually. To my anger, still producing a 404 error.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I've never had this issue before. What is happening?

Comment: Does your server meet [the requirements for pretty permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks) - Apache web server with the mod_rewrite module installed, FollowSymLinks option enabled, FileInfo directives allowed?

Comment: `.htaccess` files or mod_rewrite might not be enabled on your server... **1.** Try putting any _nonsense_ at the top of your `.htaccess` file - do you get an error? (You should get a 500 Internal Server Error.) **2.** Try removing the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper - do you get an error?

Comment: @MrWhite I do have it enabled. Getting a 500 error when I write garbage.

Comment: What about No.2 - remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper? Or include `RewriteEngine On` at the top of the `.htaccess` file, above the `<IfModule>` wrapper?

Comment: @MrWhite Tried it, still get a internal error.

Answer (score 1):

> ...remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper? Or include `RewriteEngine On` at the top of the `.htaccess` file, above the `<IfModule>` wrapper?
>   :
>   @MrWhite Tried it, still get a internal error.

That indicates that you don't have mod_rewrite installed on your server or you are not permitted to use mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` files (see the `AllowOverride` directives for the later) - that will explain why the permalinks are not working.

With the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper in place then the directives are simply not processed when mod_rewrite is not installed. It fails *silently*.

See the following StackOverflow question regarding enabling this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2